# simple select query in linq

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, contains

Lets say I have a student table and I want to display the student with ID 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT ST
WHERE ST.ID = 1
```

This is how I achive this in Linq.

```
StudentQuery = from r in oStudentDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                     where (r.Field<int>("ID") == 1)
                                     select r;
            oStudentDataTable = StudentQuery.CopyToDataTable();
```

but what if I want to display the students with these ids 1,2,3,4,5..

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT ST
WHERE ST.ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

How can I achieve this in Linq?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var result = (from r in oStudentDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              where (list.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID"))
              select r).ToList();
```

Comment: I'd prefer a `HashSet<int>` myself in case the list gets much longer.

Comment: The `List` will be translated by LINQ-to-SQL into an `in` clause, which will then be optimized by the database. I don't think that a `HashSet` would be any faster.

Comment: Can you please provider some assistance for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764687/how-to-use-linq-to-group-by-and-order-by-certain-column

Answer (score 4):

Try `IEnumerable.Contains`:

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
StudentQuery = from r in oStudentDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                 where (list.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID")))
                                 select r;
        oStudentDataTable = StudentQuery.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this also :

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<StudentQuery> result = (from r in oStudentDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              where (list.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID"))
              select new StudentQuery
              { /*
                .Your entity here
                .
                */
              }).ToList<StudentQuery>();
```