# Linq include (select * from a table)

Tags: linq

I want to know a query in linq which is equivalent to below:

```
select t1.*, (select columname from table2 t2 where id = 2)
from table1 t1
```

Comment: See if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

Comment: This might be better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859536/simple-select-query-in-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786), but with a slight twist for the sub-query being in the select:

```
var ans = from t1 in table
          select new {
              t1,
              columnname = (from t2 in table2
                            where id == 2
                            select columnname).FirstOrDefault()
          };
```

Note this will be sent to SQL as one query. This is one case where putting the sub-query in another variable will cause LINQ to send two SQL queries instead. SQL requires an (implied) `First` on the sub-query, but you could leave it off if you don't mind `columnname` being an `IEnumerable` that potentially has multiple values.